# Unable to start Ubuntu

Tags: installation, wubi, startup

I'm unable to start Ubuntu in my laptop.

I'm sharing Ubuntu with Windows 7 in my laptop, and after I install Ubuntu when I boot my laptop and choose Ubuntu as my operating system the following error appears:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
 1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next". 
 3. Click "Repair your computer "
If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator it computer manufacturer for assistance. 

 File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
 Status: 0xc0000098
 Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and have been google'ing a while now, this is what i've come to till now:
[This site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) states that recent computers, especially those more recent than 2010 uses the UEFI-booting-system, and not MRB. This may be the cause of the problem; As it says [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/694242) that wubi uses MRB to boot ubuntu (if that is true). 
May be worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

EasyBCD will help to provide dual boot options.  It is free software for personal use - 
Create new boot entry and select Windows or Linux as your primary boot,